# Qt font fallback missing entire language of glyphs

Tags: qt, fonts, fallback, fontforge

I am having some troubles with the font fallback for a qt GUI. The primary font is Tahoma, but since that lacks East Asian characters, WenQuanYi Zen Hei is being used as a supplementary font to cover the Asian glyphs. This is working fine for Chinese and Japanese, but Korean characters (which are included as part of the WenQuanYi Zen Hei font) are not displaying at all.

I have been trying to use fontforge to adjust the Tahoma font file to ignore Korean characters, but this has not yet yielded any different results.

Comment: It looks like Korean uses some kind of reference system to generate glyphs, rather than draw them out, like Chinese or Japanese do. Could this be causing a bug during fallback?

Comment: What is you have mixed Latig + Korean strings? swapping wont work....